# awk else if - best practice

Tags: shell, awk, scripting

This code works as expected.

```
grep myhost hosts.csv |
awk -F, '{if ($8 != "") print $8; else if ($7 != "") print $7; else if ($7 == "" && $8 == "") print $0}'
```

I know there are 100's of ways to skin a cat. But I was just wondering if this is the best way most effective way to do this.

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is more appropriate for this kind of question.

Comment: The clause `else if ($7 == "" && $8 == "")` should be written simply as `else`; you won't get to it if `$8 != ""` or if `$7 != ""`.  The `$8 != ""` test accounts for two of the four cases arising from the tests (it doesn't matter whether `$7` is empty or not; `$8` is printed regardless if it is non-empty).

Answer (score 3):

Ok, can you try this?:

```
awk -F, '/myhost/{print ($8!=""?$8:($7!=""?$7:$0))}'
```

OR

```
awk -F, '!/myhost/{next} $8!=""{print $8;next} $7!=""{print $7;next} 1'
```

Comment: Piping the output of `grep` to `awk` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Yes, that's true, let me fix it

Comment: I would stick with your 2nd solution: maximize clarity, minimize "clever". I would add more whitespace for readability. `!/myhost/` is the same as `$0!~/myhost/`

Comment: very nice .. what if i wanted to make my myhost a variable $1 , i like eliminating the grep. I am playing with it now and trying to add the print tolower

Answer (score 1):

FWIW I'd write it as simply:

```
awk -F, '/myhost/ {if ($8 != "") $0=$8; else if ($7 != "") $0=$7; print}' hosts.csv
```

Comment: very nice .. what if i wanted to make my myhost a variable $1 , i like eliminating the grep. I am playing with it now and trying to add the print tolower

Comment: If understand you correctty: `awk -F, -v myhost='$1' '$0~myhost { if...}'`